# Setting value of a s:hidden in javascript

Tags: javascript, struts2, hidden

I have a JSP with HTML input fields like `"username"`. I have a JavaScript method where I get the value of this field using `document.getElementById('userId').value.

Now I have a struts2 tag: `<s:hidden name="username" />`

In my JavaScript, before submitting, I need to set the value from the input text field to the Struts 2 hidden tag field. I cannot use the text directly from the input field and I need to set it to the hidden Struts 2 tag.

Comment: If you need to do this before submission you are doing something wrong. It means you rely on the client to keep the value you specified on the server - what if someone modifies it on purpose and disables your JavaScript? You **must** enforce such a thing on the server.

Comment: The hidden tag actually matches with a form variable.So on submit to the action class, the variable is set to the form variable.Hence I need to do this through javascript only.I can set a s:textfield also but I need to know if its possible to set the s:hidden value in javascript.....

Comment: Well, if the user modifies it without your JS being executed you will get the modified variable instead of the one from the hidden field.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: @DaveNewton seems OP wants to set some hidden field based on the values provided in the text field.though the motive is not clear why?

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi Oh. That seems straight-forward enough.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to give id to your hidden field then you can set it with jquery or javascript.

Following is example to set it with jquery

This is your form

this will set username from jquery;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
               $(document).on('click', '#s', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var name="Ram";
                    $("#uname").val(name);
                });
            });
</script>
```

If it is very important data then save it to session or any other scope and get it directly to action dont show it to jsp page

Answer (score 1):

1. Why cant you directly give the value to hidden field?
2. Struts2 input tags are finally converted into the normal HTML tags on page rendering, so there is nothing special you need to assign them a value. Just mention a id to the hidden element and assign the value using the javascript like you usually do

   ```
   <s:textfield id="mytext" value="yourvalue"/>
   <s:hidden id="myhidden" value=""/>


   function assignvalue(){
       document.getElementById("myhidden").value=document.getElementById("mytext").value;
   }
   ```

Comment: The thing is that the hidden variable should correspond to a bean variable defined in the Action class.When I use the s:textfield, the complte alignment is going haywire. Hence, I thought to submit the value from the hidden varaible which should correspond to the form variable

Comment: Now using the above, my hidden variable value is set but the bean variable is not getting populated.I have defined <s:hidden name="user.Name" value=""/> where Name is a variable in a bean. But its not working.the bean variable is still nulll....please help

Comment: So what is the problem using the same name to the hidden field as your bean variable?? To solve your alignment problem with textfield try using this format-`<s:textfield theme="simple" name="whatever"/>`

Comment: What about this `<s:hidden name="user.Name" value="%{user.Name}"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Struts2 tags only provides some additional functionality to work better with Struts2 flow.They are like helpers which give you some out of the box features to work closely with struts2.

In the end when your JSP will be displayed by the browser be it struts2 tag/your custom tags or any other tag library you are using will be converted in to pure HTML which is understood by your browser.

So if you have a text-field say

```
<s:textfield name="username" id="username" value=""/>
```

it will be converted in to HTML at final display like

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="">
```

Just note that if you will not provide `id` for your textfield struts2 will generate the id by itself while converting the tag code to final HTML so if you want your custom id for the textfield/any other field give it explicitly.

So you have all way to use famous javascript way

```
document.getElementById("myhidden")
```

and do what ever you want to do with the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value of a textfield to the hidden value on submit button.

Let to show you an example,
`<script type="text/javascript>`

`function setHiddenValue(){`

`document.getElementById('hiddenfield').value =  document.getElementById('textfield');`
`}`

`</script>`

`<s:hidden name="hiddenfield" id="hiddenfield"  />`

`<s:textfield name="textfield" id="textfield" />`

`<input type="submit" onclick="setHiddenValue();" />`